# Does this reworded question meet the SE requirements?

Tags: support

I have a question about my 3D Printing Stack Exchange post: [Reverse engineered complex data sets produced by a 3D Solid Scanner. What would you scan for 3D printing?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/reverse-engineered-complex-data-sets-produced-by-a-3d-solid-scanner-what-would)

Comment: Thanks in advance;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that the Stack Exchange network is a good fit for the type of question you're asking. Your question was flagged as **primarily opinion-based**. Essentially, the question you're asking is a poll or survey which the design of the Stack Exchange sites don't properly support. Here are some more appropriate solutions for what you're asking for:

- Bring up your poll in [3D Printing SE Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34216/the-hotbed-3d-printing)
- Create a [Google Form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) to conduct and analyze the survey
- Any other survey/form style site such as [TypeForm](https://www.typeform.com/) or similar

Comment: Thanks for the great advice tbm0115!

Comment: Your first option is the best... But then the problem is... The last real message in that room was nearly 4-5 months ago

Comment: I believe the OP posted a link to their poll recently