# Appeal request for my two questions

Tags: support, editing

I have a question about my 3D Printing Stack Exchange post: [What measures can be implemented to ensure equitable access to personalized treatments using 3D printing?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/22984/what-measures-can-be-implemented-to-ensure-equitable-access-to-personalized-trea)

I usually ask questions on the "Today's Featured Site", but on the 3D Printing site, I have lost the battle. Currently, I have asked just two questions on this site. This one I have asked on January 23. The other, currently deleted question, I have asked on February 13. Both the questions were closed as opinion-based. Then, I have keep on making new edits until I get a question that is good for this site. Now, in my latest edit to the other question, I try to add sourced content to clarify, but the community marks it as spam and offensive, and deletes and protects the question. So, I need to edit both the questions to make it answerable for the site. So, I have requested for an appeal here. I really cannot live without a question with the original date as February 13. Look at Facebook. When I post something on Facebook, I can change the date and time of that post to an earlier date or time. I wish that StackExchange would have a similar feature.

What is something more specific I can ask about personalized medicine and consumers?

I really need to edit both the questions into practicable answerable questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me say, thanks for trying to participate in the site.

As the [help](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) states:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Unfortunately, neither of your questions fit that criteria.

Therefore, the community voted to close.

Thereafter, any subsequent edits did not help the questions to address the initial reasons for closure (as explained more fully below)

---

The first question about the medical applications, as I had already explained in the comments, was not suitable for a Q&A site:

> I would imagine that there are a number of on-going research projects. However, research across the various fields of medicine seems rather a broad area. As such, any comprehensive answer would need to be really long, and just a list of links to projects - a list that would be continually changing as time goes by. For that reason, it doesn't seem that your type of question is particularly suitable, as it currently stands, for this site - it is just too broad a question. If you could narrow the scope of the question (to a particular field) then that might make it easier to answer appropriately

I then aggregated the links from a deleted answer, that appeared to answer your initial edit of your question, into a couple of comments, so that you could at least see them.

I then explained:

> Maybe all of the links (and associated abstracts), in these comments, could be put into one single wiki-type answer that anyone could contribute to... that is a possibility. However, that would/could still result in a never-ending list answer that gets bigger and bigger and which would/could end up breaking Stack Exchange's Q&A format. On the other hand, if multiple answers were posted, how could you select the accepted answer..?

I now realise that I mis-spoke when I said:

> If you could narrow the scope of the question (to a particular field) then that might make it easier to answer appropriately

As the issue would still remain, regardless of scope - except that the list of linked papers would be a little shorter.

Apologies for having got your hopes up, and your futile scope edits.

---

The second question was opinion based, *initially* asking about materials. Subsequent edits just *changed the subject upon which the opinion was asked*, from materials, to UX or UI (?), then to cost (for which you got a range of opinions in the comments), back to UX/UI and then finally an opinion on Octoprint. This last "Octoprint" edit contained a link to an unrelated product listing page (upon which octoprint was somewhere near the bottom), hence the spam flag.

---

To re-iterate the [help](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), neither of these questions seem to be based on actual problems that you face, but rather the start of a *discussion*. Discussions are, unfortunately, out of scope of Stack Exchange, as a Q&A site.

**Please also be aware that after a system-determined number of failed edits and re-open votes, the system (not the community or moderators) could implement a question ban or suspension. In order to avoid this, please try to ask *"practical, answerable questions"* and not opinion-based discussion based topics.**

Besides that if you continually edit the sense, or topic, of a question, then users will get confused, fatigued, or "turned off", as some comments have indicated. So, please, try to plan your question in advance so that multiple subsequent edits aren't required.

If you really need an answer to your two questions, then I would like to quote [this answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/181/4762), from a (sort of) related question:

> Unfortunately, I don't think that the Stack Exchange network is a good fit for the type of question you're asking. Your question was flagged as **primarily opinion-based**. Essentially, the question you're asking is a poll or survey which the design of the Stack Exchange sites don't properly support. Here are some more appropriate solutions for what you're asking for:
>
> - Bring up your poll in [3D Printing SE Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34216/the-hotbed-3d-printing)
> - Create a [Google Form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) to conduct and analyze the survey
> - Any other survey/form style site such as [TypeForm](https://www.typeform.com/) or similar